# OneDrive for Business Storage/Quota

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

I'm trying to programatically get OneDrive for Business Storage/Quota for all users within our tenant.

Have tried using the `https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com/_api/site/usage` API call, but this doesn't accurately represent the size of our OneDrive usage.

Has anyone had any experience of getting this information and how best to get it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such endpoint like /sites/usage according to the [documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm).

Instead call for GET --> https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive and get drive information. In the drive response you will be having **QUOTA** facet.

***[Sample response](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/drive.htm#)*** response has been truncated for readability.

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "driveType": "personal | business",
  "owner": { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.identitySet" },
  "quota": { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.quota" },

  "items": [ { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.item" } ],
  "root": { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.item" },
  "special": [ { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.item" }]
}
```

Here you can get the storage/quota information.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right _api format to get the usage statistics but you need to specify the full path to each users' OneDrive for Business site in the URL.

For example:

```
https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_mytenant_com/_api/site/usage
```

For each user in your organisation, call that REST Api URL but replace the user_mytenant_com part with the username of the current user.

By default an Office 365 tenant administrator does not have access to a user's OneDrive for Business site so I don't think you will be able to call the REST Api method without first adding your user as an administrator of their OneDrive for Business site.